# How to implement a UI update method that works both with the UI thread and other threads in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, multithreading

I am implementing a method that updates UI and can be executed either from the UI thread or from other threads. According to Javadocs, in the latter case [Display.syncExec()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#syncExec%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [Display.asyncExec()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#asyncExec%28java.lang.Runnable%29) methods should be used. Do I have to check whether my method is executed in the UI thread or syncExec/asyncExec is suitable for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing Display.syncExec/asyncExec is safe from any thread (including the UI thread), but it isn't always the best route. For instance, asyncExec will always add your runnable into the queue to execute later even if you are already on the UI thread. Depending on your usecase, that may or may not be desirable. Often, if you known you are already on the UI thread, it is better to just go ahead and execute the work item.

I like to use the following snippet in any method that needs to update UI and may be called from a non-UI thread. If called from UI thread, it executes the work immediately. If called from other thread, it uses asyncExec to schedule work in the next batch without blocking the calling thread.

```
public void task()
{
    if( this.display.getThread() != Thread.currentThread() )
    {
        this.display.asyncExec
        (
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    task();
                }
            }
        );

        return;
    }

    // Do whatever needs to be done with the UI.
}
```

Comment: My current use case is reporting an error to the user. What do you think is best in this case?

Comment: I'd say that you'd want the error immediately as it happens if you are already on the UI thread. If you are not already on the UI thread, asyncExec should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `Display.syncExec/asyncExec` should be safe when called from any thread, no matter whether it's UI or not.

One might suspect that calling `syncExec` from the UI thread results in a deadlock. This is not the case since the `syncExec` method checks first whether the calling thread is the UI thread. If so, the `run` method of the `Runnable` is executed immediately.